# FileNotFoundException when creating a proxy object using Moq and Castle

Tags: c#, moq, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a base abstract class that exists in a nuget package that I am implementing a concrete class for, something like this:

```
public class MyConcreteClass : MyBaseAbstractClass<SomeType> {

  public MyConcreteClass(IAnInterfaceOne interfaceOne, IAnInterfaceTwo interfaceTwo) : base(interfaceOne, interfaceTwo) { }

}
```

I am mocking the two parameters like so:

```
var mockFirst = new Mock<IAnInterfaceOne>();
var mockSecond = new Mock<IAnInterfaceTwo>();
```

and the concrete class like so:

```
var mockConcrete = new Mock<MyConcreteClass>(mockFirst.Object, mockSecond.Object);
```

When I try to access the `Object` property within `mockConcrete`

```
var concreteObjectInstance = mockConcrete.Object
```

I get a `FileNotFoundException`, `Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.dll'` and the debugger in VS points to the base constructor call for where the exception is coming from:

`base(interfaceOne, interfaceTwo)`

`Castle.Core` and `Moq` versions:

```
<package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Moq" version="4.5.21" targetFramework="net452" />
```

I have searched through the nuget package where the base class resides in and there are no references or usages of serilog. I [searched `Castle.Core`'s repo and found many usages of serilog](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Serilog) which I believe is a logging library. So I am a bit confused on how this exception is occuring and how I can try to resolve it so it does not throw the exception when I mock my object.

Comment: Is your concrete class the system under test or are you using it as a dependency for the actual system under test?

Comment: The concrete class is a dependency I want to mock a return value for. What I am actually testing uses it, but yeah it is just a dependency.

Comment: Does it also fail if you new up the concrete class manually and pass the two mocks. Since it is already concrete I don't see what you want to mock it given that it will already be using mocks of it's dependencies `var mockConcrete = new MyConcreteClass(mockFirst.Object, mockSecond.Object);`

Comment: So the reason I do not want to manually create the concrete and pass in the two mocks is because it has a method that hits a service. I want to mock the return value of that method so it doesn't go out and hit the service.

Comment: Then your problem is design. The service is a dependency and should then also be abstracted so that you can mock it. As it currently stands your concrete class is tightly coupled to that service. That server should be injected.

Comment: So MyBaseAbstractClass<T> has the virtual method that reaches the service. `public virtual TOutboundContract ServiceCallMethod(RestArguments arguments = null, bool forceBypassOfCache = false);`, can't virtual methods from abstract classes be mocked?

Comment: Yes. Yes they can. The dependence on that concrete service is still a design issue but I see your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through I found the cause of the problem. It actually is not related to castle or moq. It was actually caused by Metrics.NET which is a nuget package being referenced in `MyBaseAbstractClass<T>`. This line was in the base class:

```
private readonly Metrics.Timer _callTimer = Metric.Timer("", Unit.Calls, SamplingType.LongTerm, TimeUnit.Milliseconds);
```

and the exception was being thrown every time the base class was initialized on that line. I [looked at the packages `Metrics.NET` was referencing](https://github.com/etishor/Metrics.NET/blob/master/Src/Metrics/packages.config) and saw `LibLog`. So I looked into `LibLog` and saw it was [referencing `Serilog`](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=serilog). So I am not sure why `Serilog` cannot be found within those packages still, but I removed the line throwing the exception since it was unused anyways and also removed the `Metrics.NET` package. I am answering my question to make sure people know it is not a problem with Castle or Moq like I originally thought it was.